# How to change Background of datagridcell based on multiple condition WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have datagrid with some conditional row. And I want if I select particular row in datagrid, The selected color will change based on my record value. 
Suppose I have record of `Students` with `IsDropOut` Flag.

And then If I click selected record of student, Selected row will change color according to `IsDropOut` value. If it is `true` it will set selected row background to red and if `IsDropOut` is `false` it will change selected row background to green.

Maybe with like this

```
       <DataGrid.Resources>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataGridCell.IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsDropOut}" Value="true" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

But that's code is not work. So how to do it? Anyone has suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve this.. Thanks for the idea..

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsDropOut}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
          <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsDropOut" Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Comment: don't work. The member `IsDropOut` is not recognized or is not accessible.This is data binding not property in `datagridcell`